# 'Mail From:' SMTP command not working with google smtp server

Tags: smtp, gmail, telnet

I'm trying to send an email using smtp-relay.gmail.com as a relay server, but when I try to use the 'Mail From:' command, I get this error:

> c:    mail from: username@google.com
>
> s:    555 5.5.2 Syntax error. f23sm825435wmf.2 - gsmtp

Answer (score 4):

use brackets <> (some mail servers does not require this)

```
MAIL FROM: <user@example.com>
```